# Unable to download waffle package

Tags: r, package, waffle-chart

I am trying to plot a waffle chart in R studio.However,I am unable to download waffle package.I get the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘waffle’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘Rttf2pt1’
```

I wonder if anyone else has faced this problem.Thank you

Comment: Try installing `Rttf2pt1` first, then try installing `waffle`.

Comment: Hi,i had tried that but i still get the error could not find waffle function although i have both packages

Comment: Okay the issue was I had to install waffle again after downloading Rttf2pt1.Phew..finally working